# Problems with Flash Builder 4.5 and Away3D

Tags: air, flash-builder, away3d

I've got a very annoying problem with Flash Builder and Away3D.

We've got a web/mobile panorama product that uses Away3D to render the panoramas as a skybox.

I recently updated Away3D to the latest version, and found that on mobile, there is a black shape in the middle of the screen, blocking part of the panorama. It seems to start off as the whole screen, and then as you rotate it shrinks and changes shape.

I tried reverting to our previous version of Away3d, and now Flash Builder thinks it's full of errors such as invalid overrides and classes not found, and won't compile any new changes to the project. Eg -overridesaway3d.materials.methods.BasicDiffuseMethod.applyShadow
-1020: Method marked override must override another method.

So really, there's 2 problems here:

- Latest Away3D makes black shape on Mobile
- Flash Builder won't accept the Away3d code (which has been fine for ages).

Can anyone shed any light on either issues so I can get back on with it?

Answer (score 0):

lens.far setting was too far and for some reason it broke the skybox on mobile